# Change default output of gci

Tags: powershell

Say, I want to see `CreationTime` column instead of `LastWriteTime` in output of gci.

I can use `Format-Table`:

```
gci | ft Mode,CreationTime,Length,Name
```

BUT! We lose default formatting, default colorizing of `Name` column, and get array of text data instead of array of FileInfo/DirectoryInfo objects (so we can't do the piping afterwards).

Is there any way to preserve at least default colorizing for `Name` column (without going all the way manually)?

Comment: Use `Select-Object` instead of `Format-Table` to get an array of FileInfo/DirectoryInfo objects…

Comment: @JosefZ Doesn't seem so.```(gci | Select-Object Mode,CreationTime,Length,Name)[0].GetType()``` shows ```PSCustomObject```

Comment: What you see when running `gci` (*alias to* `Get-ChildItem`), is governed by format views defined in `FileSystem.format.ps1xml` file located in the `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` directory. It's ill-advised to make changes directly to it, so I'd recommend either creating your own format to a new object, or just copying the existing one, modify what you need (*in this case `CreationTime`*), and then update it using `Update-FormatData` pointing to your new \*.format.ps1xml: `Update-FormatData -PrependPath .\Desktop\FileSystem.format.ps1xml`.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala `Update-FormatData` thoroughly described here: [Perfect PowerShell Properties Part 3: Custom Formatting](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2014/05/13/PowerShell-properties-part-3.aspx). (Read all three parts.)

Comment: @AbrahamZinala  @JosefZ thanks, useful. But there is still a mystery. I exported xml according to this guide (```Get-FormatData System.IO.FileInfo | Export-FormatData -LiteralPath fmt.ps1xml```). But in table description there are strange properties that don't even exist: ```NameString```, ```LengthString```, and ```LastWriteTimeString```. I guess they are somehow dynamically generated (colors apply here?). Any ideas how to get to them?